# Product topology of compact subsets

Tags: general-topology

Suppose K,L are compact subsets of topological spaces X,Y respectively, and that KxL < W where W is open in XxY. Prove that for each x in K there exist sets U_x, V_x open in X, Y respectively and such that U_x contains x, L < V_x and (U_x)x(V_x) < W.
Hence or otherwise prove that there exist sets U, V open in X, Y respectively and such that KxL < UxV < W.

I don't see how to use compactness. Since W is open then for any (x,y) there are open sets A_x and B_y in X and Y containing x and y respectively, with (A_x)x(B_x) < W. Then take the union of these A_x and B_y over all y in L.
Then for the second part take the union of the the U_x and V_x over all x in K. Where does compactness come into it?

Comment: The union of these small products has no reason to be itself a product of two sets.

Comment: What if you fix x, then for (x,y) in W, for each y in L then there is an open set A_x in X and and open set B_y in Y, so take U_x = (union over (x,y) in W for each y in L and for fixed x)A_x and take V_x = (union over (x,y) in W for each y in L and for fixed x)B_y

Comment: Close. You have to show that you can pick one $A_x$ that fits for all $y\in L$. That's where the quasicompactness comes in.

Comment: I don't see why you need one A_x; if you take U_x to be the union of the A_x for all the y in L then doesn't it satisfy the requirements in the first part?

Comment: If $A_{x,y}\times B_{y} \subset W$ for all $y\in L$, then it does _not_ follow that $$\left(\bigcup_{y\in L} A_{x,y}\right) \times \left(\bigcup_{y\in L} B_y\right)$$ is a subset of $W$. You have that only if $\bigcup A_{x,y}$ is small enough.

Comment: Ok, I see that now. Since L is compact then there is a finite union of the B_y containing L, say B_y0, B_y1, ... , B_yn then this is V_x. So then can you take the intersection of A_x,y1, A_x,y2, ..., A_x,yn to be U_x?

Comment: Yes. Since you intersect only finitely many $A_{x,y_i}$, $U_x$ is open. Then, for every $x\in K$, you have $U_x,V_x$ with $U_x\times V_x \subset W$. I guess you see how to finish.

Comment: Yeah I see, thank you!